# Find the characteristic polynomial $f(t)$ of $T$, where $T(a,b,c,d) = (a+b,b-c,a+c,a+d)$

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

Find the characteristic polynomial $f(t)$ of $T$ and verify that the characteristic polynomial of $T_{W}$ divides $f(t)$. Where $T:\mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{4}$ and $T(a,b,c,d) = (a+b,b-c,a+c,a+d)$

This question is tied to another question where I found the basis of the $T$-cyclic subspace, $W$, generated by $e_{1} = (1,0,0,0)$. In that case the basis $\beta = \{e_{1}, T(e_{1}), T^{2}(e_{1})\} = \{(1,0,0,0), (1,0,1,1), (1,-1,2,2)\}$.

So now arriving at this question I am asked to find the characteristic polynomial of $T$ over $V = \mathbb{R}^{4}$.

The only way I know of finding the characteristic polynomial is by $f(t) = \det(T - tI)$.  I do also have the following theorem:

[image]

Is it the case that I would need to try a variety of different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ (most likely only the basis vectors) and find a $T$-cyclic subspace of dimension $4$ from which I could then apply the result of this theorem? Because the other idea I had was forming the matrix of the linear operator using  the basis vectors and then calculating the determinant, which would be very labor intensive and I have a feeling they don't want me to do that in the problem.

Is the approach I have the right one? As a question of curiosity what do we do when we want to find eignevalues for larger dimension matrices? From what I've read calculating the determinant is not efficient.

Comment: Just write down the matrix for $T-tI$ in the _standard_ basis for $\mathbb R^4$, write $u=1-t$ to make it even simpler, and take the determinant -- it ends up with only two nonzero terms in this case.

Comment: To answer your last question there are a variety of numerical methods for computing eigenvalues, listed on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix for $T$ in the standard basis for $\mathbb R^4$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
So you're looking for the determinant of
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1-t & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-t & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1-t & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1-t
\end{pmatrix} $$
This matrix has enough zeroes in it that we can simply wing it:
$$ \left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1-t & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-t & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1-t & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1-t
\end{array}
\right| =
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1-t & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1-t & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1-t \end{array}
\right| \cdot (1-t) $$
since there was only one nonzero element in the last column. And now we can just apply the well-known canned formula for a $3\times 3$ determinant -- four of its six terms vanish and we're left with
$$ \cdots = \bigl((1-t)^3 + 1\cdot(-1)\cdot 1\bigr) \cdot (1-t) = \bigl((1-t)^3-1\bigr)(1-t) $$
You could multiply out the right-hand side here, but it's more enlightening to leave it in this shape because it's easier to read off its roots this way:
$$ t=1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad (1-t)^3 = 1 \implies \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} 1-t = 1 & \implies & t = 0 \\
1-t = e^{2\pi i/3} & \implies & t = \frac32 - \frac{\sqrt 3}2 i \\
1-t = e^{-2\pi i/3} & \implies & t = \frac32 + \frac{\sqrt 3}2 i
\end{array}\right . $$

Comment: Had just started to go through the suggestion you had mentioned in the comments.  It is only over the reals, but do keep what you wrote because the complex solutions add a dimension of interest to it. I also like the substitution suggestion. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the characteristic polynomial of

$I+
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix on the right can be found to be $x(x^3+1)$ by expanding along the bottom row, and so it has roots $0,\omega^1,\omega^3,\omega^5$ where $\omega$ is a $6$'th root of unity.

It follows the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(x-1)(x-(\omega+1))(x-(\omega^5+1))(x-(-1+1)) = x(x-1)( (x-(\omega+1))(x-(\omega^5+1)) = (x^2-x)(x^2-3x+3)$